# How to add alt and title attributes field for user picture?

Tags: 7, users

In my Drupal project I have user picture enabled to all users, I want to add alt field and title field for Drupal user picture feature, so I can add my custom text instead of "user's picture" text.

I also want to utilize both fields in views as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to my own question is as follow:

I've created a custom module to change user picture alt and title for the uploaded image

first overrides [this function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) if you need to change "user's picture" in user profile page. (thanks to @jsheffers for pointing this out)

```
function MODULE_NAME_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {

  $variables['user_picture'] = '';
  if (variable_get('user_pictures', 0)) {
    $account = $variables['account'];
    if (!empty($account->picture)) {
      if (is_numeric($account->picture)) {
        $account->picture = file_load($account->picture);
      }
      if (!empty($account->picture->uri)) {
        $filepath = $account->picture->uri;
      }
    }
    elseif (variable_get('user_picture_default', '')) {
      $filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($filepath)) {
      $alt = t('YOUR CUSTOM ALT TEXT');
      $title = t('YOUR CUSTOM TITLE TEXT');

      if (module_exists('image') && file_valid_uri($filepath) && $style = variable_get('user_picture_style', '')) {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $style, 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $title));
      }
      else {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image', array('path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $title));
      }
      if (!empty($account->uid) && user_access('access user profiles')) {
        $attributes = array(
          'attributes' => array('title' => t('View user profile.')),
          'html' => TRUE,
        );
        $variables['user_picture'] = l($variables['user_picture'], "user/$account->uid", $attributes);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To make it work with views you need to create a new views handler field and extend [this handler class](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!user!views_handler_field_user_picture.inc/7)

```
class views_MODULE_NAME_handler_field_user_picture extends views_handler_field_user_picture {

  function render($values) {
    if ($this->options['image_style'] && module_exists('image')) {
      // @todo: Switch to always using theme('user_picture') when it starts
      // supporting image styles. See http://drupal.org/node/1021564
      if ($picture_fid = $this->get_value($values)) {
        $picture = file_load($picture_fid);
        $picture_filepath = $picture->uri;
      }
      else {
        $picture_filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
      }
      if (file_valid_uri($picture_filepath)) {
        $alt = t('YOUR CUSTOM ALT TEXT');
        $title = t('YOUR CUSTOM TITLE TEXT');
        $output = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $this->options['image_style'], 'path' => $picture_filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $title));
        if ($this->options['link_photo_to_profile'] && user_access('access user profiles')) {
          $uid = $this->get_value($values, 'uid');
          $output = l($output, "user/$uid", array('html' => TRUE));
        }
      }
      else {
        $output = '';
      }
    }
    else {
      // Fake an account object.
      $account = new stdClass();
      if ($this->options['link_photo_to_profile']) {
        // Prevent template_preprocess_user_picture from adding a link
        // by not setting the uid.
        $account->uid = $this->get_value($values, 'uid');
      }
      $account->name = $this->get_value($values, 'name');
      $account->mail = $this->get_value($values, 'mail');
      $account->picture = $this->get_value($values);
      $output = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account));
    }

    return $output;
  }
}
```

Make sure to call the new handler instead of the original handler by overriding [this function](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7)

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  foreach ($data as $table => $config) {
    foreach ($config as $item => $item_config) {
      if (isset($item_config['field']['handler']) && $item_config['field']['handler'] == 'views_handler_field_user_picture') {
        $data[$table][$item]['field']['handler'] = 'views_MODULE_NAME_handler_field_user_picture';
      }
    }
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: could it be possible to make only views override alt text overriding views_MODULE_NAME_handler_field_user_picture but without overriding MODULE_NAME_preprocess_user_picture.
This is to disallow user to have their own alt text but override alt text in views with replacement token for ex. when hovered text will be like " author of <some popular node title> total articles <node count> "

Answer (score 1):

You would need to override [this function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) in your template.php file and override the `alt` tag.

Another option would be to uncheck `"Enable user pictures"` in account settings and add your own custom imagefield.  Then you should be able to enable `alt` and `title` fields in the field settings.  You can also use this field in views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't add additional field to user profile/account at the moment. I want to add alt and title to user picture itself.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Cool, but `template_preprocess_user_picture` will solve part of my issue (this option is useful for user profile page and views with default image-style). So I used views with different image style (custom style) `template_preprocess_user_picture` will no longer be useful. Any other ideas?! thanks

Comment: @Aboodred1 Fields are the built-in way to do this, unfortunately if you can't use them you'll have to code something custom