# Drupal 7 Use custom Alt tag for User Photo

Tags: users

Noob here - I would like user photo alt tags to say "[firstname] [lastname]" instead of "@user's picture". Machine names are field_first_name and field_last_name

I found this answer - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/60061 but I'm still not clear on how to edit that function. Copy/paste-able code for the template.php will be greatly appreciated.